# Is there any possibility to style an [input] tag?

Tags: html, css, input

Is there any possibility to style an `<input>` tag? 
What I wrote:

```
<li><form>
    <input class="search" name="s" type="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" value=">
</form></li>
```

And the styling:

```
form{
        height: 40px;
}

.search{
        border: none;
        background-color: #7e7376;
}

input[type=search]{
        font-family: 'Overpass';
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #2c2729;
        margin-top: 4px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        height: 12px;
}
```

It looks very different on various browsers. I tried to apply some reset CSS but that didn't help. I am building a menu bar and the search box needs to look like part of it. Any help on this?

Comment: "It looks very different on various browsers" — You need to be more specific about the problem.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: What you are looking for is to style input placeholder. You can find more info about that here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-css3-placeholder-pseudo-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [appearance property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) is what you are looking for.

> The appearance property is used to display an element using a platform-native styling based on the users' operating system's theme.

```
input {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
}
```

[CSS-Tricks has a very useful article about it](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/).

Comment: @trnks_ If you want to change the placeholder, you may like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a webkit browser you can add `-webkit-appearance: none`. This will remove default browser styling. You may also want to remove the outline, border, and background.